# Can we host the same wcf service in two different computers and communicate between them? i want to call the same service in another system

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one wcf service which acts as server and client, i want to install that in different systems and communicate between them, can you please give me an example how to that,

I Have created one wcf service which have both client and server API and installed in two computers, i have created the channel factory object in client side to contact the server methods.

channel has created but i am not able to call the method, it is giving the object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: Servers have to be started before clients.  So one server has to be just a Server and started first.  Then you can start a second two port server that connects to first server as a client and also is a server.

Comment: I did that too, but same error

Comment: Is service started the same way on both PCs?  Is service set to run as an Admin or User?  I would check the event logs on the computers to see if there is more info on error.

Comment: the server is running as administrator

Comment: You say the channel is created but you are not able to call.  I assume you mean the client channel on PC with both server and client.  So when you create the client you get a null object.  Normally a server you Listen on a Port using IPAny as the address.  When opening the client you must connect to the port and the IP Address (Or PC name) of 2nd server.  You may be getting an error if you attempt to open two connections withe the same Source IP, Destination IP, and Port number.

Comment: I would put the code (both the connect and call) in an exception handler and get the StackTrace from the exception to give more details.